# I have 10 PDFs open in a Chrome window: how can I save all the PDFs on my disk at once?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, download, window, save-as

I have 10 PDFs open in a Chrome window: how can I save all the PDFs on my disk at once? I don't want to manually go on each tab and save PDF one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension named [TabSave](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-save/lkngoeaeclaebmpkgapchgjdbaekacki). Install it and open the extension. You will get all the URLs of the tabs and if you click the cloud looking button, all tabs will start to download. Or you can edit the URL list.

[image]